# How to arrange duplicate rows of data into one row

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv

I am trying to arrange duplicate data into one row using Python.

Let me show you example:
[image]

The "**Original**" dataframe has duplicate data.

The "**Goal**" is what I am trying to accomplish.

How do I go about doing this?

If I use Pandas, how would it look like?

By the way, I am getting original data from csv file.

```
 PatientID  Model#  Ear   SerNum    FName   LName   PName   PPhone

 P99999    300     Left    1234567  John    Doe Jane Doe    (999) 111-2222
 P99999    400     Right   2345678  John    Doe Jane Doe    (999) 111-2222



 PID      ModleL  SerNumL   ModelR  SerNumR FName   LName   PName  PPhone
 P99999   300     1234567   400     2345678 John    Doe     J.Doe  (999) 111-2222
```

Comment: could you include this data in your question so we can copy and paste it?

Comment: Sorry. I just added texts into the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we split our data into `left` and `right`. After that we use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to bring our data back together and give the correct `suffixes`:

```
df_L = df[df.Ear == 'Left'].drop('Ear',axis=1)
df_R = df[df.Ear == 'Right'].drop('Ear', axis=1)

print(df_L, '\n')
print(df_R)

  PatientID  Model#   SerNum FName LName     PName          PPhone
0    P99999     300  1234567  John   Doe  Jane Doe  (999) 111-2222 

  PatientID  Model#   SerNum FName LName     PName          PPhone
1    P99999     400  2345678  John   Doe  Jane Doe  (999) 111-2222
```

Now we can merge  back and give the correct suffixes:

```
df = pd.merge(df_L, df_R.iloc[:, :3], on = 'PatientID', suffixes=['Left', 'Right'])

print(df)
  PatientID  Model#Left  SerNumLeft FName LName     PName          PPhone  \
0    P99999         300     1234567  John   Doe  Jane Doe  (999) 111-2222   

   Model#Right  SerNumRight  
0          400      2345678
```

Comment: I like you merge :-)

Comment: Hi @Erfan, I like your merge approach. I have a question. If I also want to combine row(s) that have either Left side data or Right side data (meaning, one side would have a blank data), how can we list data? So, the whole output of data would list data with both sides (Left and Right ear data) as well as output of data with only one side of ear.

Comment: I found the solution using "how=outer" such as:                                                              
df = pd.merge(df_L.iloc[:, 0:3], df_R.iloc[:, 0:7], on = 'id', suffixes=['L', 'R'], how='outer')

Answer (score 1):

Best source is the official source:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

You may also want to learn about multiindex, levels, etc.

I prefer join:

```py
import pandas as pd

columns = ['PatientID', 'Model#', 'Ear', 'SerNum', 'FName', 'LName', 'PName', 'PPhone']
data = [[
    'P99999', '300', 'Left', '1234567', 'John', 'Doe', 'Jane Doe', '(999) 111-2222'],
    ['P99999', '400', 'Right', '2345678', 'John', 'Doe', 'Jane Doe', '(999) 111-2222']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
df = df.set_index('PatientID')

df = df[df['Ear'] == 'Left'].drop('Ear', axis=1).join(df[df['Ear'] == 'Right'].drop('Ear', axis=1), lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right').reset_index()
```

Output:

```py
  PatientID Model#_left SerNum_left  ... LName_right PName_right    PPhone_right
0    P99999         300     1234567  ...         Doe    Jane Doe  (999) 111-2222
```

**EDIT**:
1. Fixed, forgot to drop the column :)
2. Now with your data :)

Answer (score 1):

This is more like a `pivot` problem , so I use `pivot_table` here

```
s=df.pivot_table(index=['PatientID','FName','LName','PName','PPhone'],columns='Ear',values=['Model#','SerNum'],aggfunc='first')
s.columns=s.columns.map(' '.join)
s.reset_index(inplace=True)
s
  PatientID FName LName     ...      Model# Right SerNum Left SerNum Right
0    P99999  John   Doe     ...               400     1234567      2345678
[1 rows x 9 columns]
```